# If one of my POST Parameters contains character '+' it gets converted to ' ' instead of passing it correctly

Tags: ajax, post, browser

[image]

When passing the id "vpzYeZkOy4HpNo + DLBb4WQ ==" disappears "+" in the body of id.

Comment: Looks like you need to URL-encode your values: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 0):

Can you try passing + as a URL encoded value => %2B?

Edit: @David beat me to it